# How to run Jest/Supertest tests inside of an API directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, supertest

I have written some tests for my node API, and when I built the tests, I did so in their own directory. When I run my API locally, and then run the tests, everything works fine. Ideally, however, I'd like to move the tests over into a folder called /tests within the root directory of the API. I see examples of how to do this online, but all the examples given are using fairly simple APIs, I have a very specific node command that starts the API, any idea how I can get this all to work together in a single npm run test command?

API start command

```
"start-dev-local": "env-cmd -e devlocal babel-node --  src/index",
```

test example

```
const request = require("supertest")
const baseURL = "http://localhost:3000"

let token = ''

describe("POST /auth/login", () => {
    const newLogin = {
        email: "test@email.com",
        password: "password"
    }
    it("Should return a login token", async () => {
        const res = await request(baseURL).post("/auth/login").send(newLogin);
        expect(res.statusCode).toBe(201);
        expect(res.body.user.hasOwnProperty('token'));
        token = res.body.user.token;
    });
});
```